# Why is my Queue looping around infinetly?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I made my own implementation of a Queue ADT, but I've messed up something somewhere and I'm unable to understand what I did wrong here.

This is the queue.h for reference:

```
typedef struct op_queue *Queue;

Queue crea_queue();
void enqueue(Queue queue, int num);
int dequeue(Queue queue);
int isQueueEmpty(Queue queue);
int queueSize(Queue queue);
int head(Queue queue);
```

And this is the queue.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"queue.h"

typedef struct Item{
    int num;
    struct Item *next;
} Item;

Item *crea_item(int num){
    Item *new = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!new){
        printf("ERROR ALLOCATING");
        exit(-1);
    }

    new->num=num;
    new->next=NULL;
    return new;
}

struct op_queue{
    Item *head;
    Item *tail;
    int size;
};

int head(Queue queue){
    return queue->head->num;
}


Queue crea_queue(){
    Queue new = malloc(sizeof(struct op_queue));
    if (!new){
        printf("ERROR ALLOCATING");
        exit(-1);
    }
    new->head = NULL;
    new->tail = NULL;
    new->size = 0;
    return new;
};


void enqueue(Queue queue, int num){
    Item *temp = crea_item(num);
    if (queue->tail == NULL){
        queue->tail = temp;
    }
    if (queue->head == NULL){
        queue->head = temp;
    }
    else{
        Item *foo = queue->head;
        queue->head = temp;
        temp->next = foo;
    }
    queue->size++;
}

Item *recursive_last(Item *item){
    if (item->next != NULL){
        return recursive_last(item->next);
    }
    return item;
}


Item *find_last(Queue queue){
    Item *result = NULL;
    if (queue->head != NULL){
        result = recursive_last(queue->head);
    }
    return result;
}


int dequeue(Queue queue){
    Item *temp = queue->tail;
    int result = temp->num;
    free(queue->tail);
    queue->tail = find_last(queue);
    queue->size--;
    return result;
}


int isQueueEmpty(Queue queue){
    return (queue->head==NULL);
}

int queueSize(Queue queue){
    return queue->size;
}
```

For testing purposes, here's the main.c:

```
#include"queue.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    Queue foo = crea_queue();
    enqueue(foo, 11);
    enqueue(foo, 12);
    dequeue(foo);
    printf("you did it!!");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried reviewing the code a few times, but to no avail... The issue might be in the enqueuing function, maybe the temp?

Comment: You can't call `find_last(queue)` after you do `free(queue->tail)`. It will loop into the element you just freed.

Comment: To remove the last item from the queue, you need to set the `next` pointer of the 2nd-to-last element to `NULL`. And you can set `queue->last` to this 2nd-to-last element.

Comment: Here's an example of how you could get a pointer to the pointer to the last element which you then can use to `free` the last element and also set the pointer to it to NULL: https://godbolt.org/z/vhEsY5ajP - I removed the recursion though. Using recursion to find the last element in arbitrary long lists is not a good idea. You may run out of stack space.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I actually learned something new here. Now I understand why usually you dequeue from the head and enqueue from the tail.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the `dequeue` function

```
int dequeue(Queue queue){
    Item *temp = queue->tail;
    int result = temp->num;
    free(queue->tail);
    queue->tail = find_last(queue);
    queue->size--;
    return result;
}
```

does not change the second-to-last (if there is one) element's `next` pointer from its previous value (`queue->tail`) so `find_last` will use that [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). It also fails to update `queue->head` in the event the last element was dequeued.

Without the use of a doubly-linked list, I would suggest flipping the direction of your queue: add elements to the tail as they are queued, and dequeue elements from the *head*. This simplifies the process by not needing to scan for the element that points to your tail when the tail element is removed. Instead, when the dequeuing, the new head is simply the next element after the current head.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct op_queue *Queue;

Queue crea_queue(void);
bool enqueue(Queue queue, int num);
int dequeue(Queue queue);
int isQueueEmpty(Queue queue);

typedef struct Item {
    int num;
    struct Item *next;
} Item;

struct op_queue {
    Item *head;
    Item *tail;
};

Item *crea_item(int num)
{
    Item *new = malloc(sizeof *new);

    if (new) {
        new->num = num;
        new->next = NULL;
    }

    return new;
}

Queue crea_queue(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof *crea_queue());
}

int isQueueEmpty(Queue queue)
{
    return !queue->head;
}

bool enqueue(Queue queue, int num)
{
    Item *item = crea_item(num);

    if (!item)
        return false;

    if (isQueueEmpty(queue))
        queue->head = queue->tail = item;
    else {
        queue->tail->next = item;
        queue->tail = item;
    }

    return true;
}

int dequeue(Queue queue)
{
    Item *item = queue->head;
    int result = item->num;

    queue->head = item->next;
    free(item);

    if (!queue->head)
        queue->tail = NULL;

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    Queue q = crea_queue();

    if (!q) {
        /* handle error */;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        if (!enqueue(q, i)) {
            /* handle error */;
        }
    }

    while (!isQueueEmpty(q))
        printf("Got: %d\n", dequeue(q));

    free(q);

    puts("Done.");
}
```

```
Got: 1
Got: 2
Got: 3
Got: 4
Got: 5
Got: 6
Got: 7
Got: 8
Got: 9
Got: 10
Done.
```

As an aside, [*Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/2505965), is a good read. The usual consensus is to avoid typedefing pointers. You might think it necessary to implement an *opaque type*, and some libraries do this (notably, POSIX), but it is not a requirement (see: `FILE *`).

Comment: `typedef struct op_queue *Queue;` do not do this. A very  very bad habit

Comment: @gulpr I am well aware, thank you. If you had read the OP's code you would understand that this is not my design.

Comment: Also no `queue` NULL checks. Not your design - but it is the moment to show OP how it should be done, not to repeat his errors.

Comment: I would also suggest to have less returns from the functions (positive checks instead of negative)

Answer (score -1):

too complicated. If you store tail and head you do not need to iterate.

```
typedef struct Item{
    int num;
    struct Item *next;
} Item;

typedef struct op_queue{
    Item *head;
    Item *tail;
    size_t size;
}Queue;

Queue *push(Queue *q, int *val)
{
    size_t newsize = q ? q -> size + 1 : 1;
    if(!q)
    {
        q = calloc(1, sizeof(*q));
    }
    if(q)
    {
        if(val)
        {
            Item *i = calloc(1, sizeof(*i));
            if(i)
            {
                i -> num = *val;
                if(!q -> head)
                {
                    q -> head = i;
                    q -> tail = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    q -> tail -> next = i;
                    q -> tail = i;
                }
                q -> size = newsize;
            }
            else q = NULL;
        }
    }
    return q;
}

int pop(Queue *q, int *val)
{
    int result = -1;
    Item *i;
    if(q)
    {
        if(q -> head)
        {
            i = q -> head;
            *val = i -> num;
            result = 0;
            q -> head = i -> next;
            q -> size--;
            free(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

size_t qsize(Queue *q)
{
    return q -> size;
}

int main(void){
    Queue *foo = push(NULL, NULL);
    int val;
    if(foo)
    {
        for(int x = 11 ; x < 15; x++)
        {
            push(foo, &x);
        }
        while(!pop(foo, &val))
            printf("The val is %d\n", val);
    }
    free(foo);
 }
```